# How to check a variable is a list and the data type inside this list are all integers, if not then throw the exceptions accordingly?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5, 'hole']

try:
    if type(x) == list:
        print("all ok")
    else:
        raise Exception('Variable is not a list')

except Exception as error:
    print('Caught an error: ' + repr(error))
```

As you can see I am checking that the variable `file` is in fact a list. If it is not then the exception will be raised. Which to be precise it is a `ValueError` but I just generalize it to `Exception`.

However, I need to be even more specific. I would like my setter also to check that the elements inside the `file` list are all integers.

Can anyone help me how to this and raise another Exception that says: "all elements inside your list are not integers"?

Comment: Try `if all(type(element) == int for element in file):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last version of your code already raise the exceptions as you want. I just want to suggest you to use isinstance function besides type() and ==.

```
try:
    if isinstance(x, list):
        print("all ok")
        if all(isinstance(element, int) for element in x):
            print("all integers")
        else:
            raise ValueError('all elements inside your list are not integers')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Variable is not a list')

except ValueError as error:
    print('Caught an error: ' + repr(error))
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why you prefer isinstance than type()?

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension here; `all` can return `False` after it sees the first non-`int` value, so there's no reason to generate a full list of `bool`; just use a generator expression. `all(isinstance(element, int) for element in x)`.

Comment: @ananvodo it is just a recommendation given in [PEP8 Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use isinstance to check whether a variable is of the given type and raise exception accordingly.

For invalid data,

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5, 'hole']
>>> if not isinstance(x, list): raise ValueError("Not a list")
...
>>> if any(not isinstance(i,int) for i in x): raise ValueError("List elements are not int")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: List elements are not int
```

For valid data,

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> if not isinstance(x, list): raise ValueError("Not a list")
...
>>> if any(not isinstance(i,int) for i in x): raise ValueError("List elements are not int")
...
```

Or,

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5, 'hole']
>>> try:
...     for n in x:
...         if n==int(n): pass
... except ValueError:
...     raise ValueError("Expected a list of integers")
... except TypeError:
...     raise TypeError("Expected a list")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
ValueError: Expected a list of integers
```

Comment: I have read that isinstance is not that safe. 
Do you think according to your experience I won't have problems using this inside a class setter and for a python exe program I am building?

Comment: Where have you read that? It's the preferred way to check the type of an object.

Comment: You must have isinstance is not safe because it also checks if the given object is an instance of the subclass. If you fell so, I'd suggest to just proceed and throw a type error when failed, as I've added in the edits

Comment: If an object is an instance of a subclass of `int`, it's still an instance of `int`. That's one of the fundamental principles of inheritance, not a bug or a problem.

Comment: (If it *is* a problem, it's with the definition of the subclass, not with `isinstance`.)

Comment: BTW, any reason you are using `any(not ...)` instead of `all`?

Comment: No, not really!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5, 'hole']

try:
    if type(x) == list:
        print("all ok")
        if all(type(element) == int for element in x):
            print("all integers")
        else:
            raise ValueError('all elements inside your list are not integers')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Variable is not a list')

except ValueError as error:
    print('Caught an error: ' + repr(error))
```

Comment: Don't use `type(element) == ...` to check for types; use `isinstance`. `all(isinstance(element, int) for element in x)`.